# How to display field text instead of the ID for a model connected by a foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple model (kit) connected by another model(client_id) with a foreign key, and also by a `ManyToMany` field. I have a form view for the kit model, in which user can create new kits, by selecting a few products, and then choosing which client it is made for. Problem is, the fields are being displayed correctly, but with only ID displayed, instead of their names. User does not know what is he selecting as he does not know the ID of all products or clients. How should I approach this ? I searched on SO but found nothing useful.

### Code

models.py

```
# Parent model connected with both models
class Kit(models.Model):
    kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    kit_info = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    components_per_kit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_id = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='kit_product')
    quantity_per_kit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    kit_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kit_owner')

# connected by foreign key
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    client_company = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

# connected by many to many field
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <h2 class="mb-3">Add a new Kit</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <a href="{% url 'employee:products_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

### Current output

[image]

Comment: Can we see your view and template code? There are a couple ways to do this.

Comment: Are you looking for [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str) method?

Comment: Whats in the `kewl websites`?

Comment: @ToniSredanović I have a list of kewl websites e.g. https://xmas.astral.de/# and whatnot which on viewing reminds me how powerful a website can be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use __str__**.

I asked for your code just in case you have some strange setup, but this is probably the easiest way for you to do it.

Change your `Product` model to this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

That will replace the `Project Object (1)` with whatever is in the `product_name` charfield.

EDIT: See below for a good comment about Python 2.

Comment: In case you're using Django, this one might need when your project using Python <3. `from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible`, add `@python_2_unicode_compatible` on top of your Model

Comment: Hey, I had to ask,  is there a method where when I select any of the ```client```, some of the fields get filled by data from the select client ???

Comment: @YantraLogistics try this tutorial.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Answer (score 3):

A fairly simple way to do this would be adding string representation to your models. For example in your product model add:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Also, if you can use any of the model's fields in there, so for example if you want both id and name you can do something like:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.id, self.product_name)
```

Comment: Hey, I had to ask, is there a method where when I select any of the client, some of the fields get filled by data from the select client ???